# How do i resolve an error while passing request verification token to asp.net mvc action?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am using datatables.net in my asp.net mvc application 
to create and populate Tables. 
While doing so i ran into an issue that when i pass requestverification token, I got error and tables did not gets created and populated.
If i do not pass any token and remove  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute from action method, i do not get any issue.

While debugging I found out token was null value

```
var head = request.Headers.Get("__RequestVerificationToken");
```

below is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            var token = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();

            //jQuery DataTables initialization
            var oTable = $('#myTable').DataTable({

                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/myapplication/MyReport/LoadReport",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "datatype": "json",
                    "headers" : { '__RequestVerificationToken': token }
                        },
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "Store", "name": "Store" },
                    { "data": "Form", "name": "Form" },
                    { "data": "Order", "name": "Order" },
                    { "data": "Sku", "name": "Sku" },
                    { "data": "RequestedDate", "name": "RequestedDate" },
                    { "data": "Reason", "name": "Reason" }
                ],
                "responsive": true,
                "rowReorder": {
                    selector: 'td:nth-child(2)'
                },
                "serverSide": "true",
                "order": [0, "asc"],
                "processing": "true",
                "language": {
                    "processing": "Loading. Please wait..."
                },
                "dom": "<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'p>>" +
                    "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
                    "<'row'<'col-sm-4'i>>"
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation shows you a good way to get those tokens and it also reveals, that you have a conceptual error. Asp.net does not generate one but **2** tokens. One is stored in the form and the other one in a cookie. You need to send both back to the server, to satisfy the anti forgery requirements.

You can use this razor function to get build the token:

```
<script>
    @functions{
            public string TokenHeaderValue()
            {
                string cookieToken, formToken;
                AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);
                return cookieToken + ":" + formToken;                
            }
        }
</script>
```

and then add this value to your header:

```
headers: {
        'RequestVerificationToken': '@TokenHeaderValue()'
}
```

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks

Comment: Sir, Thank you. I realized that I was missing @Html.AntiForgeryToken(). I added that html helper at the top of the body.